# How do I add measures to a matrix and achieve my desired format

Tags: matrix, powerbi, measure

I am currently making a daily store sales table and am having trouble adding 2 measures that I created (previous week's sales and % change).

The issue I am having is when I drop the 2 measures into my matrix, the format changes to something completely unusable. See below.

Also, I want all 7 days to show even if they are not complete. Example: Today is Monday, so I only have Sunday's sales, but I still want Monday-Saturday to show at the top, and all figures Monday-Friday should be blank or "-".

**Desired Result**

[image]

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add separate measures for each of your column headings, then they'll all lay out in a table like you want.  EG

```
Monday = CALCULATE(sum(FactInternetSales[SalesAmount]),DimDate[DayNumberOfWeek] = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm trying to implement it right now, but I can't get the formula working. In order to filter on the current week of sales, I added a column to my date table called 'Week Rank'. How would you change the formula to get it working?

'code'
Sales CW Monday = calculate(sum('Transaction_Data'[TotalSales]),FILTER(all('Dates'),Dates[Week Rank]=MAX('Dates'[Week Rank]),Dates[DayOfWeekName]="Monday"))